# send several strings through a pipe to a child process

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, system-calls, dup

I want the child process to listen in a loop the parent process. If it receives "exit" from the parent it terminates and if it receives "cmd" will read again for the actual command to execute using system().
So far I have this code, but the second reading just gives me the same ("cmd")

child:

```
pid = fork();
            if(pid == 0){           
            close(fd_pipe[1]);  // Close writing end
            dup2(fd_pipe[0],0); close(fd_pipe[0]);
            //close(fd_pipe[0]);

            //create file descriptor for user file
            int userFile_fd = 
            open(users_table.at(get_user(u_id)).get_filename().c_str(), O_APPEND|O_WRONLY);
            //redirect output to user file
            dup2(userFile_fd,1);
            close(userFile_fd);

            //listen in a loop till receive "exit"
            while(true){

                char buf[100];

                read (0, &buf, 100);
                cout << buf << endl;

                //logout
                if(strstr(buf, bye) != NULL){
                    cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
                    kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
                    break;
                }

                //command
                else if(strcmp(buf, cmd) == 0){

                    read (0, &buf, 100);
                    cout << "reading buf again: "<<buf << endl;

                    system(buf);
                }
            }//end while

            }//end if (child process)
```

parent:

```
while(status == true){

    //get input
        cout << ("ucmd>");
        getline (cin, command);

//some preprocessing code and then...

        //this works fine
        else if(command.compare(logout)==0)
        {
            cout << " UM: Loggin out USER-"<<u_id<<" associated pipe ID: "<<user_pipe[u_id]<<endl;
            char exit2[] = "exit";
            write (user_pipe[u_id], exit2, sizeof(exit2));//sends exit message
        }

        //cmd
        else if(command.compare(cmd)==0)
        {   

            write (user_pipe[u_id], cmd, sizeof(cmd));//cmd command
            write (user_pipe[u_id], argument.c_str(), sizeof(argument.c_str()));//cmd command
            //call_cmd(u_id, argument);
        }
```

Comment: You can't use `cout << ("ucmd>");` in C — that's C++.  You need to know how many bytes were read — you don't capture that information so you're working blind.   The code you've provided isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
That means we have to do too much work to test your code.

Comment: You can't write correct Unix code while ignoring the result returned by every system call.

Comment: "You can't use cout << ("ucmd>");" the question has tag c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong to me:

```
write (user_pipe[u_id], cmd, sizeof(cmd));//cmd command
write (user_pipe[u_id], argument.c_str(), sizeof(argument.c_str()));
```

How is `cmd` defined? Your code is only correct if it is defined as a fixed size array of characters. The second line looks definitely wrong: `argument.c_str()` returns a `char const *`, so `sizeof(argument.c_str())` will return `sizeof(char const *)` *independent* of the actual value of `argument`. You can try something like this:

```
char const *carg = argument.c_str();
write(user_pipe[u_id], carg, strlen(carg) + 1);
```

That way the full string (including terminating `NUL`) should be transferred to the child.

Then in the child I think you have to be more careful as well. You do

```
read (0, &buf, 100);
```

But then consume only the first `NUL` terminated string from `buf`. The `read` operation may have read more than that. You should check the return value. In particular, make sure that `read` returns a value > 0. Otherwise nothing may have been read (there may have been an error) and the contents of `buf` are unchanged.

Comment: thanks, yes this line was  wrong, "write (user_pipe[u_id], argument.c_str(), sizeof(argument.c_str()));".